# Rows don't get deleted correctly

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete rows that have the value of `Rating` equal to `NaN` and the `sum` of single `columns` is `<50`. Rating contains integer values in the range of `[1,5]`. This is my code for deleting them.

```
bow = bow.loc[~(bow['Rating'] < 1), ~(bow.sum(0) < 50)]
```

But when I print the dataframe I can still see `NaN` ratings. The `sum` part does its job correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

This is how `bow` was created:

```
bow = df.Review2.str.split().apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
rating = df['Rating']
df_rating = pd.DataFrame([rating])
df_rating = df_rating.transpose()
bow = bow.join(df_rating)
bow.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need check non missing values by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
bow = pd.DataFrame({'Rating':[4,5,np.nan,5,5,np.nan],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[12,33,5,7,144,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,94,2,4]})

print (bow)
   Rating  C    D   E
0     4.0  7   12   5
1     5.0  8   33   3
2     NaN  9    5   6
3     5.0  4    7  94
4     5.0  2  144   2
5     NaN  3    0   4
```

---

```
bow = bow.loc[bow['Rating'].notnull(), bow.sum() >= 50]
```

Or:

```
bow = bow.loc[bow['Rating'].notna(), ~(bow.sum(0) < 50)]
#oldier pandas versions
#bow = bow.loc[bow['Rating'].notnull(), ~(bow.sum(0) < 50)]
print (bow)
     D   E
0   12   5
1   33   3
3    7  94
4  144   2
```

Comment: Perfect, thx! Would you know why `<1` does not work tho? Is it because `NaN` is not comparable to integers (in the sense that it isn't located anywhere specifically in the integer range)?

Comment: @StefanoPozzi - Because there is inverted condition, find all values which are `NOT` less as `1`, maybe you think `bow = bow.loc[bow['Rating'] >= 1, bow.sum() >= 50]`

Comment: @StefanoPozzi - it means get all rows which are higher or equal as 1, but better is for check non NaNs use `notna` or `notnull`